# regex: получить число без пробелов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть два числа в строке:

90041 009

Использую выражение:

`(?<account>(900\d{2}\s\d{3}\b))`

результат: 90041 009

Возможно ли присвоить именованной группе account значение 90041009, т.е. **без** пробела?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Регулярные выражения ищут совпадение слева направо, и в одну подмаску можно захватить только непрерывную последовательность символов. Используйте две подмаски - `(?<account1>900\d{2})\s(?<account2>\d{3})\b` - и объедините их значения.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ответы - в ответы.